# How to kill a process with kill function in c++?

Tags: c++, linux, kill

I'm learning processes in Linux. I need to write a task which operates processes(Create, kill, change nicety, and suspend). I've already written that program, but kill and suspend are not working. To fix that I launched that program as a superuser, but this didn't help me. What do I need to do to fix that bug?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    float l,r;
    //  system("gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c \" /home/neo/Desktop/OSLab8/childprocess/a.out 1 2 3\"'");
    cout<<"Enter left and right side of the loop\n";
    cin>>l>>r;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter number of processes\n";
    cin>>n;
    //   cout<<"Process 0";
    int currentPid;
    string cmd;
    double s = l;
    double step = (r-l)/n;
    cout<<"Father id "<<getpid()<<endl;
    int mode;
    cout<<"Enter 1 to time measure mode, 2 - demo mode\n";
    cin>>mode;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) // loop will run n times (n=5)
    {

        switch(currentPid = fork()){
            case 0:
                cmd = "gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c \" /home/neo/Desktop/OSLab8/childprocess/a.out "+to_string(s)+" "+to_string(s+step)+" "+((mode==1)?"":"1 ")+"\"'";
                system(cmd.c_str());
                return 0;
            case -1:
                printf("Error when forking\n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        cout<<"Son process id - "<<currentPid<<endl;
        s+=step;
    }
    if(mode==1){}
    else{
        int choise;
        do{
         cout<<"1 Set priority of processes "<<endl;
         cout<<"2 Kill processes "<<endl;
         cout<<"3 Suspend:"<<endl;
         cout<<"4 Exit";
         cout<<"Your command: ";
         cin>>choise;
         switch(choise)
         {
         case 1:
                {
                    cout << "Enter ID of the process: ";
                    int id; cin >> id;
                    cout << "Enter the priority (from -20 up to 19): ";
                    int prior; cin >> prior;
                    setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS,id,prior);
                    break;
                }
          case 2: 
                {
                    cout << "Enter ID of the process: ";
                    pid_t id; cin >> id;
                    kill(id,9);
                    break;
                }
          case 3: 
                {
                    cout << "Enter ID of the process: ";
                    int id; cin >> id;
                    kill(id,SIGSTOP);
                    break;
                }
          case 4: 
                {
                    cout << "Enter ID of the process: ";
                    int id; cin >> id;
                    kill(id,SIGCONT);
                    break;
                }
        }
        }while(choise!=4);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not doing any error checking.  What is the return value of `kill`?  And if it indicates failure, what is the value of `errno`?

Comment: Using `kill()` from c++ will not be different than using it from c.

Comment: @PaulSanders errno returned SUCCESS. However, the process was alive.

Comment: It looks like you could simplify your example code by hardcoding some of the options instead of taking input from the user. The simpler your example, the fewer places bugs have to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eliminated the unrelated "stuff" and came up with this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 2) { 
        std::cerr << "Usage: kil <process ID\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pid_t process = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    if (kill(process, 9)) {
        std::cerr << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

I did a quick test, killing a couple of processes, and it seems to have worked correctly. If you want to kill the process a bit more...gently, you might want to use `kill(process, SIGINT)` instead.

Comment: @ПашаМороз: working (or not) doesn't really depend on whether a process is a child, but on whether this executes under a user account that has the right to kill the process in question. If you try to kill something like pid 1, chances are that's going to fail. If it's a process you launched normally, you should also be able to kill it.